# Scanning negative with silverfast and plustek opticfilm 8200i gives just color bars on half the image

Tags: error, usb, negative-scanner

I had problems scanning dia film with Silverfast and plustek opticfilm 8200i. I just get about half the image and than just color bars. I'm using Windows 10 and I have a Samsung C460W printer/scanner connected via USB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily concerned with operating systems, applications, and hardware drivers.

Comment: There where no information to be found on the Internet about this problem and it's pretty hard to trouble shoot so I just wanted to share it and maybe help someone else with the same or a smilar issue

Comment: If your answer resolved the issue (or at least closed the question in your mind), please go ahead and mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trouble shooting I came to the conclusion that there where a conflict between the Plustek Opticfilm 8200i negative scanner and the Samsung C460W printer driver. When I killed the CDAServer (CDASrv.exe) process the scanner just started working as normal. CDAServer is a part of "Samsung Easy Printer Manager" and does not need to run all the time so I disables it on startup.